# Javascript table with for

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table

I'm new to Javascript and  I have been trying a Javascript table with a for loop all the day. I want to get the value of a cell. I'm doing like an "Excel app". Please check what is wrong. I just fixed things in answers ....

```js
var MatriXcel = ( function( window, undefined ) {

  var matriz = [];
  var matrizJson;
  var row = 5;
  var col = 6;

  function getData(){
    return matriz;
  }


  function addRow(){
    var newCol = [];
    for (var i=0; i < col; i++){
        newCol.push("");
    }
      matriz.push(newCol);
      this.draw();
    }

   function drawTable(){
    var table = "<tr><th></th><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th><th>E</th></tr>";
    for (var i=0; i < matriz.length; i++){
      table += "<tr>";
      for (var x=0; x < matriz[i].length; x++){
        if (x == 0){
          table += "<th>"+(i+1)+"</th>";
        }else{
        table += "<td><input type='text' onkeyup='MatriXcel.save("+i+","+x+",this)' value='"+matriz[i][x]+"'></td>";
        }
      }
      table += "</tr>";
   }
   document.getElementById("tabla").innerHTML = table;
   }

   function saveInfo(irow, xcol, content){
    matriz[irow][xcol] = content.value;
  }


   function getMatch(){
    var tabla = document.getElementById("tabla");
    search= document.getElementById("word").value;
    var re = new RegExp(search,"gi");
    var row;
    var col;
    for (var i = 0; i< tabla.rows.length; i++){
        row = tabla.rows[i];
            for (var j; j<row.cells.length; j++){
                col = row.cells[j];
                 if(re.test(row.textContent)){
                     row.style.color="rgb(239, 19, 109)";
                    alert(row.textContent);

                }else if(re.test(col.textContent)){
                  col.style.color="rgb(79, 2, 133)";
                 }

            }

    }


    }

  function saveLocal(){

    matrizJson = JSON.stringify(matriz);
    console.log(matrizJson);
    window.localStorage.table = matrizJson;

    // matrizJson = JSON.parse(matrizJson);
    // console.log(matrizJson);

  }

  function init(){
    if(typeof window.localStorage.table === 'string'){
      matriz = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.table);
      this.draw();
    }
  }

  return {
    addRow : addRow,
    draw : drawTable,
    save : saveInfo,
    get : getData,
    local : saveLocal,
    init : init,
    search : getMatch,
  };

} )( window );
if (window.localStorage.length == 0){
  MatriXcel.addRow();
  MatriXcel.addRow();
  MatriXcel.addRow();
  MatriXcel.addRow();
  MatriXcel.addRow();
}else{
  MatriXcel.init();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ExcelApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="search" value="" placeholder="write here" id="word">
  <input type="button" value="Search" id="trigger" onclick="MatriXcel.search()">
  <table id="tabla">

  </table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: `tr`s have no `value`, you've to check for `col.textContent` or `col.innerHTML`, not `row.value`, in a way nikhil has proposed in their answer.

Comment: @Teemu - I missed the value part. Thanks for adding. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is an issue with your way of checking regular expression.

For example, in place of this

```
if(re == row.value){
```

it should be

```
if(re.test(row.value)){
```

Additionally, please update the code as suggested by **@Teemu** in the comments

> you've to check for col.textContent or col.innerHTML, not row.value

Comment: thank you guys....  right now I realized what is my problem  but i still cant fix  it... the cell return a empty string despite i write someting!

Comment: Not a problem. Can you share a plunker/fiddle?

Comment: @AaronR Does your cell contain an `<input>` element? Then you need to get the value from that element, not the cell. It would help if you showed the whole HTML.

Comment: @Barmar - magnificent